# How to get open/close from opening hours by current time

Tags: java, android, time, kotlin, compare

I have a `android` project about online restaurant order. and I got some problem with time logic

I got restaurant open or close time by [`String`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/index.html) :

- Restaurant 1 : `open at "16:00"` and `close at "02.00"`
- Restaurant 2 : `open at "02.00"` and `close at "16:00"`

If this time `at "18:00"` the Restaurant 1 should be open.

I have tried the code below like this, 
But Restaurant 1 still close :

```
val open = "16:00"
val close = "02:00"
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
val time = calendar.time
val currentTime: String = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(time)

if(currentTime.compareTo(open) >= 0 currentTime.compareTo(close) < 0){
    // do something is open
}
else{
    // do something is close
}
```

I using `kotlin`, maybe somebody can help me using `java` too

Comment: Are you sure about "currentTime.compareTo(open) >= 0 currentTime.compareTo(close) < 0" it seems missing &&

Comment: Or a `||`? Depends on whether the closing time is past midnight. Also @ValentinMichalak

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3):

If you're comparing time values (hours and minutes), you shouldn't compare them as Strings, but as the things they really represent: a time-of-the-day.

In java there's [the java.time classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) (in JDK >= 8). In older versions, the same classes are available in the [Threeten backport](http://threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Initially I thought I could use a `LocalTime` (a class that represents a time of the day), but the problem is that local times start at midnight and ends at 11:59 PM, so it can't handle the case of restaurant 1, that closes at the **next** day.

So you'll have to choose between a `LocalDateTime` (that represents a date and time), or a `ZonedDateTime` (if you want to consider Daylight Saving Time effects). I'm using the latter, but the code is similar for both types:

```
// timezone I'm working on (use JVM default, or a specific one, like ZoneId.of("America/New_York")
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
// today
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(zone);

// times
// 16:00
LocalTime fourPM = LocalTime.of(16, 0); // or LocalTime.parse("16:00") if you have a String
// 02:00
LocalTime twoAM = LocalTime.of(2, 0); // or LocalTime.parse("02:00") if you have a String

// restaurant 1: opens today 16:00, closes tomorrow 02:00
ZonedDateTime rest1Start = today.atTime(fourPM).atZone(zone);
ZonedDateTime rest1End = today.plusDays(1).atTime(twoAM).atZone(zone);

// restaurant 2: opens today 02:00, closes today 16:00
ZonedDateTime rest2Start = today.atTime(twoAM).atZone(zone);
ZonedDateTime rest2End = today.atTime(fourPM).atZone(zone);

// time to check
String timeToCheck = "18:00";
// set time - or use ZonedDateTime.now(zone) to get the current date/time
ZonedDateTime zdt = today.atTime(LocalTime.parse(timeToCheck)).atZone(zone);

// check if it's open
if (rest1Start.isAfter(zdt) || rest1End.isBefore(zdt)) {
    // restaurant 1 is closed
} else {
    // restaurant 1 is open
}
// do the same with restaurant 2
```

If you don't need to account for DST changes, you can use a `LocalDateTime` - just ommit the calls to `atZone` and the result is a `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Good Answer, but I suggest changing your code example to instantiate `LocalTime` objects explicitly separately and pass as arguments. This would make the logic more clear as the `16:00` and `02:00` values come from outside the logic being discussed (set as business policy by the restaurant managers).

Comment: @BasilBourque Indeed, the code is better this way, thanks!

Comment: Yes, and how about naming the t1 t2 vars to something meaningful like `openingTime` and `closingTime` or similar restaurant trade jargon.

Comment: Because t1 is the openingTime of restaurant 1 and closingTime of restaurant 2, but I'll think of better names, hold on..

Comment: sorry before, the `ZoneId` need API 26, and I cannot apply on API 19